# triggering an action of button from another class in the main method

Tags: java, button

Hello while I was following a tutorial I have learnt a way to trigger response in the main class from a click of a button in another class.

So what I have done is that I have a ToolBar class with some code as below

```
private JButton helloButton;
private JButton goodbyeButton;

private StringListener textListener;

public Toolbar() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    helloButton = new JButton("Hello");
    goodbyeButton = new JButton("Goodbye");

    helloButton.addActionListener(this);
    goodbyeButton.addActionListener(this);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    add(helloButton);
    add(goodbyeButton);

}

public void setStringListener(StringListener listener) {
    this.textListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();

    if (clicked == helloButton) {
        if (textListener != null){
            textListener.textEmitted("Hello\n");
        }
        //textPanel.appendText("Hello\n");
    } else {
        if (textListener != null){
            textListener.textEmitted("Goodbye\n");
        //textPanel.appendText("Goodbye\n");
    }
}
}
```

Then in StrinListener Interface I have

```
public interface StringListener {

public void textEmitted (String text);

}
```

Finally in main I get the two together by

```
        toolbar.setStringListener(new StringListener (){

        @Override
        public void textEmitted(String text) {
            textPanel.appendText(text);

        }

    });
```

what I am curious about is that why does clicking a button trigger response in main method "every time" I click?

so the click is being passed onto textemitted method in StringListener interface and that is received by toolbar.setStringListener in main method. But what is invoking it to work over and over whenever I click the button?

shouldn't the code be read only once unless there is while loop or another loop of some sort?

Thanks

my main class

```
    public MainFrame() {
    super("Hello World");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    textPanel = new TextPanel();
    btn = new JButton("Click Me!");
    toolbar = new Toolbar();
    formPanel = new FormPanel();

    toolbar.setStringListener(new StringListener (){

        @Override
        public void textEmitted(String text) {
            textPanel.appendText(text);

        }

    });

    formPanel.setFormListener(new FormListener(){
        public void formEventOccurred(FormEvent e){
            String name = e.getName();
            String occupation = e.getOccupation();

            textPanel.appendText(name + ": " + occupation + "\n");
        }
    });

    add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(formPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    setSize(600, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: When you register an `ActionListener` to a component, it gets called _every time_ an `ActionEvent` occurs on the component, this is the normal behaviour.

Comment: yes but why does toolbar.setStringListener in the main method also gets called every time when action listener is invoked? @Berger

Comment: Could you post your main class ? Also, what makes you think that `toolbar.setStringListener` is called every time ?

Comment: because that is the only connection I make between the buttons in toolbar and write of text in the text panel and the main frame @Berger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is behaving as expected.

Remember that when you set the textListener, the Toolbar class holds on to an instance variable (of the textListener), and therefore it is kept alive as long as your program is running or until the toolbar object is destroyed. Just because it is an anonymous inner class doesn't mean that the object is destroyed after the method textEmitted is ran once.

Comment: so triggering actionListener triggers textListener.textEmitted("Hello") but where is this method being called?

Comment: You're setting the textListener in your main class, which is saved as a variable in your toolbar object. Every time you click on one of your buttons the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method is called, and since the textListener is not null (remember you set this in your main class) the textEmitted method of the textListener is called. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: So textEmitted ("Hello") in toolbar class sets every other class that calls that interface to have textEmitted("Hello") instead of textEmitted() which is what I have in the interface itself?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.
Your interface simply defines a method that you can implement in other classes, which is essentially what you are doing in your main class. The method in your interface doesn't do anything except define the signature (that is parameters and name) and returnvalue of the method which classes (or implementations if you will) of that interface must implement.

Comment: Yea I really don't know how to put this right but if I try, what I am asking is what is the connection between the action performed that has textEmitted("Hello") and main method which simply performs textEmitted(String text). Of course if the text received is somehow "Hello" then that will be appended to textPanel "Hello" what is setting the paramter String text to be "Hello"?