# Coordinating click of a button in one class with another using SWING

Tags: java, swing

Hi guys I have already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35574638/261156) closely related to this but I have seem to have confused people in explaining my inquiry.

Basically I was following a tutorial and in my `MainFrame` class, I have this code:

```
toolbar.setStringListener(new StringListener(){
    @override
    public void textEmitted(String text){
        textPanel.appendText(text)
}});
```

Where `toolbar` is an instance of class `Toolbar` and `textPanel` is an instance of `TextPanel` class.

StringListener interface has one method as below.

```
public void textEmitted(String text);
```

Then I have override of action listener in `ToolBar` class where I have a `JButton` called `helloButton`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
    If (clicked == helloButton){
        if (textListener != null){
            textListener.textEmitted("Hello")
}}}
```

What I am curious about is that so if button is clicked textListener.textEmitted("Hello") is invoked. But then how is it being received by `mainframe` when it is just calling for instance of `textEmitted` with just `(String text)`? What's making "Hello" in parameter of `textEmitted` in `Toolbar` class to be passed into `textEmitted(String text)` of mainframe?

Comment: Why not post a [mcve]?

Comment: Is this Swing? `StringListener`, `TextPanel`?

Comment: @forJ What is `StringListener`? I have never heard of it. Is it a 3rd party package?